# what is the use of MSG structure and what are it parameters stands for?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am new to vc++ and i am creating a win32 window application. I have default project created in my visual studio. While going through the code i have found `MSG msg;` . I searched a lot about what is its use and what is the meaning of its parameters. I have found a very short description in msdn.

```
typedef struct tagMSG {
  HWND   hwnd;
  UINT   message;
  WPARAM wParam;
  LPARAM lParam;
  DWORD  time;
  POINT  pt;
} MSG, *PMSG, *LPMSG;
```

the description about the parameter and use of msg structure was very short to understand to me. So please can anyone elaburate it to me.

Comment: [Conceptual: Messages and Message Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Removed `.net` tag, added `winapi` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid having anything to do with this structure if possible. All you generally need in visual studio c++ to make use of messages are the SendMessage() and PostMessage() functions, which are used to generate messages if you need to do that, plus a message map in anything that receives messages. The message map will route the message to a specific function which will usually only see the wParam and lParam message parameters, or no parameters at all. There are a number of special message map entries which use functions with extra parameters from the message, often pt.

If you are *really* writing all your code at the Win32 level and not making use of MFC and the message map support, things are a lot harder! What you need is a single function that handles messages sent to a given window type, which should use a switch statement driven by the message value to call message-specific functions, usually passing wParam and lParam to them. The doc on WindowProc plus googling for this name should help you get to grips with this.

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses the MSG structure to pass many kinds of things to your program, including keys, mouse movements, clicks, changes made to your windows, etc. The usage of the parameters is different for different messages, so for details you need to look up a specific message. You should use a book or tutorial that shows you the basics of creating a Win API program. There you will encounter several example messages that you must handle.